# Outputting image with underlined text using php GD library

Tags: php, gd

What is the best way to display underlined text and output the result as image with GD or any other library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using the Unicode underline combining character `U+0332`.

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = "&#x0332;U&#x0332;d&#x0332;e&#x0332;r&#x0332;l&#x0332;i&#x0332;n&#x0332;e";
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';


// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of FREE PHP CAPTCHA out there that come with a lot of customization, download one and see what exactly happens behind the scene. Also have a look at this [link](http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/create-image.shtml)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I am using this...

```
    $font = imageloadfont($font_file);  
$font_width = ImageFontWidth($font);
$font_height = ImageFontHeight($font);
    $str_width = strlen($text)*$font_width;
    ImageLine($image, $left, $top+$font_height, $left+$str_width,  $top+$font_height, $color);
```