# How to underline a certain word in a GD string?

Tags: php, gd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outputting image with underlined text using php GD library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692411/outputting-image-with-underlined-text-using-php-gd-library)

I want to underline a certain word in a GD string. Is there a specific way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

1. I assume text can be rotated. You know where the word lies so ... The way of doing this is simply using the **imageline** function /it draws a line between two points/. Here is an example usage in php [GD : imageline](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageline.php).
2. If text is always orthogonaly aligned to the coordinate system you can use **imagefilledrectangle** too.
3. If your font file contains the underlined characters solving the problem is a bit easier. Use these special characters' codes in your string instead :)